# Problem with reallocating dynamic string array( without using vector )

Tags: c++, string, dynamic-arrays

```
int size = 2;
string *s = new string[size];
s[0] = "First"; 
s[1] = "Second";

//reallocating memory and increasing its size
size++;
s = (string*)realloc(s, size * sizeof(string));//here is an error
s[2] = "Third";


// Error: realloc():invalid pointer\
//        Aborted core is dumped
```

For example the same approach with dynamic int array which works fine

```
int size = 5;
int *a = new int[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) a[i] = i*(3);
++size;
a = (int*)realloc(a, (size)*sizeof(int));
a[size-1] = 132321;
```

Question:
**How realloc is different for string and int???**

Note!

1. I was thinking which tag is more suitable for my post c or c++ tag. Since I use string I decided to use c++ tag.
2. I know that I can use vector, but my assignment is about using dynamic string array without using a vector.

Comment: `realloc` is for a pointer obtained from `malloc` or `realloc`. Not for a pointer obtained from `new`. The complement to `new` is `delete` and it has no `realloc` parallel.

Comment: @JohnFilleau but, how it comes that for (int) it works fine? (P.S Thank you, I have solved my problem)

Comment: @raksa — it’s just bad luck that it seems to work fine.

Comment: the `malloc` family and `new` *may* use the same underlying memory allocation, or they may not. Your `realloc` may have just extended the present memory address, or it may have created a new memory block and copied your integers. It's easier to copy plain old data types (integers) than C++ objects (`string`). For the actual answer, you'll have to look at your compiler's `realloc`, `new`, and `string` implementations.

Comment: Also note that @PeteBecker 's comment above isn't a typo. Undefined behavior acting normally is very unlucky. In software development we prefer to know right away if something is wrong. Otherwise the silent error may also be deadly.

Comment: *but my assignment is about using dynamic string array without using a vector.* -- They're still teaching C++ this way in school (assuming this is a school assignment), even after `std::vector` has been part of C++ for 24 years now?   Obviously, whoever gave this assignment never mentioned that `realloc` does *not* create objects, so usage of it for non-POD types like `std::string` will not work.